# Finding WiFi Signal Strength Codename One

Tags: codenameone

Is there a way to find the WiFi signal strength with `Codename One`?

I want to do it in android.

Comment: What do you mean "code name one"? Are you referring to network SSID?

Comment: @SwiftingDuster click the tag...

Answer (score 0):

You can use an approach of native interfaces similar to [this](https://github.com/littlemonkeyltd/codenameone-connectivity). I'm not sure if there's an option to get that information in iOS though.